# Using float gives "call to overloaded function is ambiguous" error

Tags: c++, overloading, ambiguous

I'm overloading the function `add()`, but when I used the `float` datatype it is showing an error. However, when I change it to `double`, then it's working fine. Why is `float` causing the error?

Code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class students{
    private:
        int i;
        float f;

    public:
        void add(int b){
            i=b;
            cout << "First Int: " << i;
        }
        void add(float c){
            f=c;
            cout << "Second Int: " << f;
        }

};

int main(){
    students obj;
    obj.add(9);
    obj.add(5.5);
}
```

Errors:

```
In function 'int main()':
[Error] call of overloaded 'add(double)' is ambiguous
[Note] candidates are:
[Note] void students::add(int)
[Note] void students::add(float)
```

Comment: Change `obj.add(5.5);` to `obj.add(5.5f);`.

Comment: 5.5 is a double not a float. ``5.5f`` is a float literal.

Comment: Oooh Waoo Great, little change.. Can you little explain difference of f in float?

Comment: Since you were confused by what is happening, it should be obvious that having two methods only distinguished by the argument type, but doing different things, is a very, very bad idea. Now consider that for example size_t could be unsigned int, long, or long long on different implementations, so f (sizeof (1)) could call different methods if you do that kind of overloading!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`5.5` is a `double`, but none of your functions take a `double` argument. So, the compiler gets confused on whether to call the function with the `int` parameter, or the function with the `float` parameter. So, you get a an error saying it is ambiguous.

That is why when you changed the function to have a `double` parameter, the error no longer came, because now there is a function which can take a `double` argument, and thus there is ambiguity there.

You can also fix the problem by calling the function as

```
obj.add(5.5f);
```

Adding the `f` after a number makes it to a float.

Let's look at the C++ Standard

**§ 2.13.4**

> 1 A floating literal consists of an integer part, a decimal point, a
>   fraction part, an e or E, an optionally signed integer exponent, and
>   an optional type suffix. The integer and fraction parts both consist
>   of a sequence of decimal (base ten) digits. Optional separating single
>   quotes in a digit-sequence are ignored when determining its value. [
>   Example: The literals 1.602’176’565e-19 and 1.602176565e-19 have the
>   same value. —end example ] Either the integer part or the fraction
>   part (not both) can be omitted; either the decimal point or the letter
>   e (or E ) and the exponent (not both) can be omitted. The integer
>   part, the optional decimal point and the optional fraction part form
>   the significant part of the floating literal. The exponent, if
>   present, indicates the power of 10 by which the significant part is to
>   be scaled. If the scaled value is in the range of representable values
>   for its type, the result is the scaled value if representable, else
>   the larger or smaller representable value nearest the scaled value,
>   chosen in an implementation-defined manner. **The type of a floating
>   literal is double unless explicitly specified by a suffix. The
>   suffixes f and F specify float, the suffixes l and L specify long
>   double.** If the scaled value is not in the range of representable
>   values for its type, the program is ill-formed.

( Sorry for posting all of it, but you can learn more about `float`s this way )

Comment: Hi thanks allot problem solved.. But I'm little confused about f literal can you explain is just float required f? why double not required d? is it c++ language rule? can you give me any keyword to search about it? or any link? sorry I'm new to c++

Comment: @AsifMushtaq , you can't convert it to a `double` with `d`, `f` for `float` is available, but no `d` for `double`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Comment: @ArunA.S Okay Got it..!! Thanks also to Alank Stokes

Comment: @AsifMushtaq , I've added a small ( okay it's quite big, but still, compared to all that given in the standard, it's quite small ) excerpt from the c++ standard.

Comment: Good @ArunA.S Got it..!! Again thanks